# How to find out expected size of Xcode's app icons

Tags: ios, xcode

In xcode's 5.1.1 in Launch Image default section when i click on the specific launch image it shows me what the expected size for that image is. However, when i do the same in AppIcon it doesn't tell me what size would fit there. I have to place icons for iOS 5-8 so where on Xcode do i find out what sizes are needed for AppIcons? I can't find it.

Comment: My trick is to add a huge image for one (just one) icon holder, then compile it, Xcode will tell you the expected size for that specific icon holder. Now you repeat the process for the next holder. You have to do it one by one, or you will not be able the know the required size for every specific icon.

Comment: This sucks sooo bad I have no word for it. Xcode is miserable

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Apple guidelines:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html